# using Catalyst::Model::MenuGrinder

Tags: perl, catalyst

I am trying to add a dynamic menu to my WebApp using `Catalyst::Model::MenuGrinder` 
the documentation isn't very clear on how to configure access to via roles using this model.
has anyone implemented dynamic menu's using this Model?
I found this article in the [Catalyst Advent calendar](http://www.catalystframework.org/calendar/2010/12) and have set it up correctly I just don't know how to configure it to restrict menu options based on roles.

Any help would be appreciated
thanks

Comment: did you tried looking the the base class documentation `WWW::MenuGrinder`. Even I have not used it though.

Answer (score 1):

As documented in the [RequirePrivilege](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMenuGrinder%3a%3aRequirePrivilege) module, you restrict a menu entry based on privileges by adding keys like `need_priv` and `need_user_in_realm`. MenuGrinder "privileges" correspond to Catalyst authentication "roles", so if you want to require that a user has the role "admin" for a section, you just do

```
<item>
    <label>Admin Section</label>
    <need_priv>admin</need_priv>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look at your template file which generates the menu actually. Let's say for example that the "Clothes" menu should be display for admins only. 
You can edit you xml file, like:

```
<item role="adminonly"><label>Clothes</label>...
```

and after that you should only check in the menuitem BLOCK if the user has the desired role:

```
[% BLOCK menuitem %]
<ul [%- IF menu.class %]class="[% menu.class %]"[% END %]>
[% FOREACH item = menu.item %]
[% IF item.role %]
    [% IF c.user_exists && c.check_user_roles( item.role ) %]
    <li [% IF item.active %]class="active"[% END %]>
      <a href="[% item.target %]">[% item.label %]</a>
      [% IF item.item %]
      [% PROCESS menuitem
         menu = item
      %]
    [% END %]
    </li>
    [% END %]
[% END %]
[% END %]
</ul> 
[% END %]

[% PROCESS menuitem %]
```

PS: Never tested the above code

Comment: Thanks Dimitar I got that piece working. Their is a plugin "RequirePrivilege" thats supposed to able to hide menu choices based on a users role etc. This module would be really helpful if the Author provided some meaningful documentation. Thanks for your help

Comment: you are very welcome. It would be really useful if he provides some examples